# How to transpile index.html with babel?

Tags: html, babeljs

I have a webpage with ES6 modules that I want to transpile with babel to ES5. Following the babel documentation on https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation, I can successfully transpile the javascript folder with `./node_modules/.bin/babel js -d target` but they don't transpile any HTML there. How can I transpile my `index.html`? Using it with the same syntax fails:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel index.html -d index2.html
SyntaxError: index.html: Unexpected token (1:0)
> 1 | <!DOCTYPE html>
    | ^
  2 | <html>
  3 | 
  4 | <head>
```

**MWE**

```js
export default "Hello World";
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script type="module">
    import message from "./js/message.js";
    window.message = message;
    </script>
    <button onclick="alert(`Message: ${window.message}`);">Get Message</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm using babel 6.24.1 (babel-core 6.25.0) with npm 3.10.10. I know I don't need modules for this MWE, the real page is much more complex.

P.S.: I want to continue developing the untranspiled version to preserve my workflow. I want to use the transpiled code only for production.

Comment: Babel does not implement browser module support.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Babel is a JavaScript transpiler, it doesn't deal with HTML, or even JavaScript embedded in HTML.

Rewrite your HTML to use external JavaScript. Use `addEventListener` instead of intrinsic event handler attributes. Then apply Babel to the JS files.

Comment: The problem is that my code is in modules and I can't include modules without using module syntax in my HTML (sorry, forgot to add this requirement: I want to develop without babel and only use it for production). Also, isn't it bad style to let my JavaScript know about my HTML elements?